# INNER JOIN one table with two others as though they were outer joins

Tags: sql, inner-join, postgis

I have three tables in a postgreSQL 9.5 database:

```
big_table:
 - geom_location
a:
 - geom_location
 - name
b:
 - geom_location
 - name
```

The geom_location fields are postGIS fields that have been indexed.  The a and b tables are on the order of 200K rows, while the big_table is on the order of 20M rows.
I need to create a select statement that yields the following results:

- a_name - If there is a big_table entry within 2Km of the geom_location in table a, this would be its associated name.  Otherwise, it would be null.
- b_name - If there is a big_table entry within 2Km of the geom_location in table b, this would be its associated name.  Otherwise, it will be null.
- geom_location - The geom_location within 2Km of the entry in either table a, b, or both.
- I do not want to get back any rows where both a_name and b_name are null.

The following is close to what I want, but it requires all three geom_locations to be within 2Km:

```
SELECT t.geom_location, a.name as a_name, b.name as b_name
FROM big_table t 
INNER JOIN a ON ST_DWithin(t.geom_location, a.geom_location, 2000) 
INNER JOIN b ON ST_DWithin(t.geom_location, b.geom_location, 2000)
```

This is also pretty close, but it doesn't combine the rows the way I want:

```
SELECT t.geom_location, a.name as a_name, null as b_name
FROM big_table t 
INNER JOIN a ON ST_DWithin(t.geom_location, a.geom_location, 2000) 
UNION
SELECT t.geom_location, null as a_name, b.name as b_name
FROM big_table t 
INNER JOIN b ON ST_DWithin(t.geom_location, b.geom_location, 2000)
```

It seems like there should be should be some sort of syntax that does a "mostly" inner join -- that is, where two tables make an inner an inner join with respect to the first table, but a full join with respect to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT t.geom_location, a.name as a_name, b.name as b_name
FROM big_table t LEFT JOIN
     a
     ON ST_DWithin(t.geom_location, a.geom_location, 2000) LEFT JOIN
     b
     ON ST_DWithin(t.geom_location, b.geom_location, 2000) AND a.name IS NULL
WHERE a.name IS NOT NULL OR b.name IS NOT NULL;
```

Alternatively, you can combine `a` and `b` together:

```
SELECT t.geom_location, ab.name, ab.which
FROM big_table t JOIN
     ((SELECT a.name a.geom_location, 'a' as which
       FROM a
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT a.name b.geom_location, 'b' as which
       FROM b
      )
     ) ab
     ON ST_DWithin(t.geom_location, ab.geom_location, 2000) ;
```

EDIT:

I was actually thinking that the above solution might have some performance difficulties.  It works with simple data types, but complex types are always a bit more troublesome.  But, you can still do what you want.  Here is a variation of your `union` approach:

WITH ta as (
      SELECT t.geom_location, a.name as a_name, null as b_name
      FROM big_table t INNER JOIN
           a
           ON ST_DWithin(t.geom_location, a.geom_location, 2000
     ) 
    SELECT ta.*
    FROM ta
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.geom_location, null as a_name, b.name as b_name
    FROM big_table t INNER JOIN
         b
         ON ST_DWithin(t.geom_location, b.geom_location, 2000)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM ta
                      WHERE t.geom_location = ta.geom_location
                     );

I'm pretty sure `=` should work on the location column.

Comment: I think it would, but unfortunately using ST_DWithin in a left outer join like this does not use its indexes.  A postgres explain on that query comes back with a cost in excess of 2 trillion!